# Linked Server Error: Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server

Tags: sql-server-2016, pervasive

I have SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU6 Enterprise Edition on a server **Serv-A**.
And PervasiveSQL on another machine/VM **Serv-B**.

I have installed 64 bit ODBC Driver of PervasiveSQL on **Serv-A** and created a System DSN named **PervDSN**.

I created a linked server using PervDSN, named [**Server_Name**].

Now, when I execute these SELECT statements

```
select * from [Server_Name].[Database_Name]..Table_Name;

select * from openquery([Server_Name], 'select Column_Name from Table_Name') Table_Name')
```

I get same error

`Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Server_Name" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Server_Name".`

and core dump created in SQL Logs. Here is the main error it has

> 2019-04-25 23:14:11.22 spid152     DumpCallbackHk::CreateCabFile: at
>   2060 g_CabDdfFile file is null, normally because nocollectors added
>   any files, exiting 2019-04-25 23:14:11.22 spid152
>   DumpCallbackHk::CollectFiles: at 481 failed at CreateCabFile with
>   error: 0x80004005 2019-04-25 23:14:12.89 spid152     External dump
>   process return code 0x20000001. External dump process returned no
>   errors.
>
> 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     ***Stack Dump being sent to
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0164.txt 2019-04-25
>   23:17:30.42 spid152     SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 152 generated
>   fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is
>   terminating this process. 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     *
>   ******************************************************************************* 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     * 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152
>   * BEGIN STACK DUMP: 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     *   04/25/19 23:17:30 spid 152 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     * 2019-04-25
>   23:17:30.42 spid152     * 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     *
>   Exception Address = 00000001800157FD Module(odbcci64+00000000000157FD)
>   2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     *   Exception Code    = c0000005
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION 2019-04-25 23:17:30.42 spid152     *
>   Access Violation occurred writing address 00000000468C0098 2019-04-25
>   23:17:30.42 spid152     * Input Buffer 124 bytes - 2019-04-25
>   23:17:30.42 spid152     *               select * from
>   [Server_Name].[Server_Name]..Table_Name;

I'm stuck on this for last 2 days. Solution will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen that error with various data types .  Try eliminating columns until the SELECT query works.  You might check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794381/what-would-cause-a-linked-server-to-return-a-limited-amount-of-data